# Connecting to a PostgreSQL database through pq returns a "bad connection" error

Tags: postgresql, go

I am making a web app in Go and PostgreSQL using two different computers. The setup is the same on both computers (Ubuntu with last versions of Go and PostgreSQL). The problem is that I cannot get my app to connect to the database on my laptop.

I use this piece of code:

```golang
func (db *Database) Dial(user string, password string, dbname string) {
    var err error
    db.Conn, err = sql.Open("postgres", "user="+user+" password="+password+" dbname="+dbname+" sslmode=require")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection to " + dbname + " not possible!")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.Conn.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Ping to " + dbname + " not possible!")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

And I get:

> Ping to my_database not possible!
>
> driver: bad connection

I found many questions on SO with the same error, but I found no solution that would solve my case.

Also, on my laptop, just like on my desktop computer, there is a user *postgres* and I can connect to the database through *psql*, so the daemon is active and the password is right. I use the exact same setup and code on both computers.

My question is: how do I get more information about the error? I find "bad connection" to be too vague. I'm sure that a bit more of information would help me a lot.

Also, do you have an idea of would could cause the error?

**Update**

The PostgreSQL log says this:

> 2014-09-29 14:23:26 EDT FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
>
> 2014-09-29 14:23:26 EDT DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 92: "host    all             all            127.0.0.1/32            md5"

But I double checked the password and it shoud be fine. I can also log in as the *posgres* user, run the *psql* command and execute queries.

Comment: What happens if you set sslmode=disable?

Comment: The exact same error shows up.

Comment: Does anything useful appear in the postgres log?

Comment: Yes, it says `"password authentication failed for user "postgres"`, but the password is good. I have access to the postgres user and using the psql command I can edit the tables and rows. This is weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to fix this.

I log in as *postgres* and run *psql postgres*. In other words, I connect to the *postgres* database. Then I run the command \password and enter a new password.

I entered the exact same password that I have been using since the beginning and somehow now it works.

The problem is solved, but if someone has an idea about what could have been the cause, I'm interested. Maybe it has something to do with password expiration?

Comment: Your password must have been wrong. Were you typing it in each time or using host credentials or something with `psql`? I've been using Go and PostgreSQL on all kinds of configurations and I've never come across this.

Comment: I was typing it every time I wanted to use *psql*.

Comment: Super strange! Do comment if you ever figure out what happened or you can reproduce it.

Comment: The same problem, I have changed password as you did, but not works.

Comment: Same issue here as well. :/